# Handle .load() Not found error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to work with an image but what if the image doesn't exist ? How can I pass a timeout or something on load function so I can stop it ?

I need this because before loading the image I generate a div that say "Loading image" and if load function return a 404 error message my div will never disaper.

```
//generate <div id="myDiv">Loading image ...</div>
$('<img src="dasdasd.as"/>').load(function(){
     $("#myDiv").hide(); -> this will never happen
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/George02/uG4t9/) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**.error()**](http://api.jquery.com/error/)

From Docs (Emphasis mine)

> The error event is sent to elements, such as images, that are referenced by a document and loaded by the browser. **It is called if the element was not loaded correctly.**

```
$('<img src="dasdasd.jpg"/>').load(function(){
    $("#myDiv").hide();
}).error(function(){
    alert('Error occured')
    $("#myDiv").hide();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/uG4t9/2/)

Comment: That makes difference between me and experienced web developers . Thank you sir !

Comment: @George02, Glad I could help, eventually you get there :)